# android not executing http post

Tags: java, android, http-post

I am trying to connect to a url locally using emulator in my android project when it gets to the point of making the contact to the url connection the next line does not execute. this is the snippet of the code

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void...params){
            InputStream is=null;
            String result="";
            try{
                System.out.println("this is specs6"  );
                HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
                System.out.println("this is specs8"  );
                HttpPost httppost= new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/API/getSpecialization.php");
                HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                System.out.println("this is specs7"  );
                // Get our response as a String.
                is = entity.getContent();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

from the above code specs 8 and spec 6 prints to the console but spec 7 never prints. Please what could be wrong?

Comment: Do you get an error?  Stack trace?

Comment: no error...............

Answer (score 0):

apatche `HttpPost`  is no longer Work with android 
 you have to use [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) or use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

**Update**

`HttpUrlConnection` constructor doesn't take a string as a parameter
however you have to do something like this

```
URL url=new URL ("10.0.2.2/Api/getSpecialization.php") // in order to pass the url to  HttpUrlConnection
```

then

```
HttpUrlConnection post=new HttpUrlConnection(URL)
```

Don't forget to place http request insude Async class because it's a separate thread  and it doesn't work with Main Thread (UI Thread)
but you will can use a handler inside async task in order to change some component with UI thread

**UPDATE2**
this is how you can read the response

```
 OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
     writeStream(out);

     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);
```

Comment: I am trying this and I am getting error 

HttpURLConnection httppost= new HttpURLConnection("http://10.0.2.2/Api/getSpecialization.php");

Comment: Please can u flesh your answer up a bit

Comment: HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

Comment: can you pose the stack trace please ?

Comment: Check my Update2 this will show you what is the correct way to read the response